# Download voice messages with WhatsApp cloud API

Tags: node.js, twilio, whatsapp

I am attempting to create a WhatsApp bot using the official WhatsApp cloud API with Node JS. The bot's objective is to listen for incoming voice messages, download them, and then send a transcription of the message.

However, the official documentation specifies that the API only supports audio files. Is there any workaround to this limitation?

I attempted to use the official method of downloading media files with the WhatsApp cloud API, but unfortunately, the request returned an error message saying "I'm sorry, we didn't find anything".

However, I noticed that Twilio API provides a way to achieve this, which makes me wonder if there is another endpoint that support the download of voice messages using the WhatsApp Cloud API?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. I've been playing around with postman.

1. So first send a get request to [https://graph.facebook.com/{{Version}}/{{Media-ID}}?phone_number_id=](https://graph.facebook.com/%7B%7BVersion%7D%7D/%7B%7BMedia-ID%7D%7D?phone_number_id=)<phone_id> to get the media URL.
2. Then you'll send an authorized GET request to the returned URL with your bearer token and you'll get back the media.

note: if in any case you send an unauthorized GET request to the media URL it will be revoked and you'll have to start over again from the top to get a new media URL.

Meta just have a lot of security on WhatsApp data.

HERE IS THE SAMPLE CODE IN PYTHON:

```
def get_whatsapp_media_url(media_id: str, phone_number_id: str) -> bytes:
     url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/{web_hook_version}/{media_id}?phone_number_id={phone_number_id}"

     headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {meta_access_token}",}
     response = get(url,headers=headers,)
     file = get(response.json()["url"], headers=headers)
     return file.content
```

EXAMPLE USAGE:

```
input_bytes = get_whatsapp_media_url(audio_path, phone_number_id)

temp_file = "temp_2.opus"

# save the data into a temp file
with open(temp_file, "wb") as f:
     f.write(input_bytes)
```